# ggplot plot confusion with facet_wrap and fill

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data frame:

```
x| y | z | d
1| 0 | A | 0.1
2| 1 | B | 0.01
3| 0 | C | 0.01
```

Where:

> `x` are random numbers. 
> `y` is either 0 or 1. 
> `z` is finit model. 
> `d`
>   is between 0 and 1.

I want to create `facet_wrap` using `z`, and fill it by `y` using the following code:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, fill=y)) +
 geom_density(alpha = .5) +
 xlim(c(0,.10)) +
 theme_bw() +
 facet_wrap(~z)
```

How can plot it ?

Comment: What is your expected result? runs fine. but not informative with just three data points.

Comment: because your y is not a factor. try 'as.factor(y)' in your layer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your fill variable should be a factor or group. Here is a replication of your questions, I used different values for the dataframe:

```
x <- rnorm(99)
y <- rbinom(99,1,.5)
Z <- rep(c("A", "B","C"), 33)
d <- runif(99)

ggplot(dd) +
  geom_density(alpha = .5, aes(x = x, fill = as.factor(y))) +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_wrap(~z)
```

I took out xlim because the values are not all in that range, and here is the plot:

[image: plot]